# nginx and apache on same physical server - how to configure?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, apache-2.4

I need to run apache and nginx on one physical server. Preferably both listening to 443 but on different domains. As I learned this is only possible with two IPs. From an old doc I found a working example for ubuntu 10.04 and want to get it running for ubunut 16.04.

In this setup there are 2 ips:

```
enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:4f:d8:fb  
          inet addr:192.143.56.200  Bcast:192.143.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe4f:d8fb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:323 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:241 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:32078 (32.0 KB)  TX bytes:128319 (128.3 KB)

enp0s8:1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:4f:d8:fb  
          inet addr:192.143.56.201  Bcast:192.143.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

portforwarding with iptables:

```
sudo iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.56.201       tcp dpt:https redir ports 8000

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.56.201       tcp dpt:https redir ports 8000

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

nginx conf:

```
    listen 8000 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:8000 ssl http2 default_server;
```

In theory this should work. Unfortunatelly it does not. While apache is stoped and nginx is running, I cann access the files with :8000 inside the url. Leaving the port away I do get a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Once I start apache, it will take over the connection and provide an error.

Thank you in advance for any help on this!

Comment: You can have one listen for both domains and proxy back to the other.

Comment: Would this lower the performance? How about SSL Termination, would this happen at nginx?

Comment: tell your servers to listen on the specific ip's, if you don't specify the ip and just the port, they will grab all interfaces available.

Comment: There is a negligible effect on performance. SSL termination would happen at the web server that is first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the IP the interface on which nginx should listen.

If you add:
    listen 8000 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:8000 ssl http2 default_server;

it will listen on 8000 port, on all ipv4 interfaces IP's (1st line) and on all ipv6 interfaces IP's (second line).

Therefore, to make nginx to only listen on port, say 443, of say IP address 192.143.56.201  , you will need something like:
 listen 192.143.56.201:8000

Please note though that I'm not sure that nginx is able to listen only on an interface alias (your setup shown only one interface with an extra alias).

You migh either test it, or directly consider adding a second, independent interface (a second network card). Using VLANS (which are different from network alias) shoudl work as well, but you would need  a 802.1Q capable switch (so it can tag /untag vlan on the packages)